# Run time error fs.readdirSync is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2

I want to develop an e-commerce mobile app using rest API of Shopify and ionic 2. I am using nodejs package [**shopify-api-node**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node) for the rest API of Shopify. I installed this package using `$ npm install --save shopify-api-node` in ionic 2 but when I run this app on the browser using `ionic serve` it throws error like this

> Run time error  fs.readdirSync is not a function.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as Shop from 'shopify-api-node';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    Shopify: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.Shopify = Shop({

      shopName: 'shopionic.myshopify.com',
      apiKey: '8b5656da6e30449007471c02a601f799',
      password: '6bf651769f403b0efdefa482c1750bc4'

    });

    this.Shopify.order.list({ limit: 5 })
    .then(orders => console.log(orders))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

  }

}
```

Comment: Why would you use a server side library in your client side app?

Comment: fs is the filesystem api in node. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/34736547/4826457 for same error in a different library

Comment: are you using something like webpack?

Comment: @TGW ionic2 by default uses webpack..

Comment: I think this library will work only on backend side. I will have to look for a library that works on browser. Thanks for the answers sir much appreciated.

Comment: Then maybe this issue is connected to this: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447 here it says this is some issue related to webpack. I was facing same while using react this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `shopify-api-node` inside your Ionic App which Impossible. this library works only on nodeJS in the backend side, You have to look for a library that works on browser and then you can use it within you mobile app.

Comment: I developed an woocommerce mobile app using node js. I used this package for woocommerce https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api and it works perfect.

Comment: but you used it in the backend side , doesn't you?

Comment: No Sir, I used woocoomerce as i mentioned above for shopify.
here is the documentation of woocommerce rest api https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/